# Not able to execute script with parameters within a SSH script

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, scp

I have this ssh script which ssh to remote server and then scp .seq files back to the original server..

ssh script

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

localServer=`hostname`
echo $localServer
#fetching the remote server credentials from sftp.conf
while read line
     do
     if [[ $line =~ ^#  ]];
        then
        continue;

     else
         serverIP=`echo $line|cut -d',' -f1`
         userID=`echo $line|cut -d',' -f2`
     fi
     break;
     done < sftp.conf

for ((;;)) {
     #now logging into the remote server
     ssh $userID@$serverIP 'sh /data/admin/scripts/SapcmedadpebM/test/sub_script.sh $localServer $userID'
     echo "script is running"
     sleep 10;
     }
```

scp script on the remote server-

```
#---------parameters
user='root'
server='mhedr1'
ipPath='/data/admin/scripts/SapcmedadpebM/test'
opPath='/data/admin/scripts/SapcmedadpebM/test/files'

cd $ipPath
for file in `find -maxdepth 1 -mmin +1  -name "*.seq"`
#for file in *.seq
do
mv $file ./temp
scp ./temp/$file $2@$1:$opPath
echo $?
rm -f ./temp/$file
#echo $files>>abcde
done
```

now problem is when I use parameters($localServer & $userID) with scp script it throws error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Temporary failure in name resolution connection lost"
on the other hand when I hard code these parameters within the script it works fine. could anyone pls tell me why scp script not accepting parameters when I am executing it from local server using ssh....please let me know if you need more clarity...thanks

Comment: Variables within single quotes are not expanded... e.g. `foo=bar; echo '$foo'`...

Comment: OMG..how stupid I am.. I have replaced single quotes with double...and now it is working fine....thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 0):

In bash environnement you can use $HOSTNAME variable. $userid variable cannot be resolve with simple quote when you are invoking SSH.

Try :

```
localServer=$HOSTNAME
echo $localServer
#fetching the remote server credentials from sftp.conf
while read line
     do
     if [[ $line =~ ^#  ]];
        then
        continue;

     else
         serverIP=`echo $line|cut -d',' -f1`
         userID=`echo $line|cut -d',' -f2`
     fi
     break;
     done < sftp.conf

for ((;;)) {
     #now logging into the remote server
     ssh ${userID}@$serverIP "sh /data/admin/scripts/SapcmedadpebM/test/sub_script.sh $localServer ${userID}"
     echo "script is running"
     sleep 10;
     }
```